# How do you change the playback speed of an HTML video with keyboard shortcuts in a Chromium extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chromium extension that increments/decrements the playback speed of HTML videos when I hit key combinations like `<c-.>` and `<c-,>`. This will also be my first (and probably the last) extension if I can get it working.

I didn't know how to listen to specific key presses within an extension, so I looked up how to use the API Chromium provides, where I can also change the shortcuts on `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` even after loading the extension. Then I came across a 2-line command that changes the playback speed. Using these, I wrote the following `manifest.json` and `background.js`.

Though, when I load the extension, I get an error that says `background.js:17 (anonymous function)` and the extension does not function when I play a video (on [puffyan](https://vid.puffyan.us/), for example).

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "NeverPlayBack",
    "description": "Change the playback speed of html videos with YT shortcuts.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "author": "jrw",
 "icons": {
      "128": "icons/128.png",
      "256": "icons/256.png",
      "512": "icons/512.png"
   },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true},    
    "commands": {
        "increase-speed": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Period"
            },
            "description": "Increase playback speed"
        },
        "decrease-speed": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Comma"
            },
            "description": "Increase playback speed"
        }
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    switch (command) {
        case 'increase-speed':
            increasespeed();
        case 'decrease-speed':
            decreasespeed();
            break;
    }
});

/**
* Gets playbackRate, adds 0.25 to it and stores the new value in playbackRate.
*/

function increasespeed() {
const video = document.querySelector("video");
    video.playbackRate + 0.25 = video.playbackRate;
                  }
function decreasespeed() {
const video = document.querySelector("video");
    video.playbackRate - 0.25 = video.playbackRate;
}
```

Comment: I could ask about the particular error I am getting but I believe that would be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).